# How to allow only positive number to be entered in editorforfield in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want a field to allow on positive number. I tried below attempt:

Model

```
[Required]
[GreaterThanZero(ErrorMessage = "Only positive number allowed.")]
public int PositiveNumber { get; set; }
```

View

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PositiveNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PositiveNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PositiveNumber, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Custom Validation

```
  public class GreaterThanZero : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var x = (int)value;
            return x > 0;
        }
    }
```

Question: Above solution works fine. I want to know is there any simple way to achieve it. By just using some inbuilt framework annotation/helpers or even [FoolProof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)?

Kindly note that: using editorfor helped to allow only numbers (it is smart) but how about just the positive numbers.

Comment: Have you tried regular expression validator

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This accepts only positive numbers.

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
 [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Only positive number allowed")]
```

Comment: this will validate number bigger than or equal to 1, not positive number

Answer (score 5):

This should be correct.

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Only positive number allowed.")]
```

Comment: It seems 0 should not be an option. "Zero is defined as neither negative nor positive" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer